# MySQL delete entries in database which are more than a month old

Tags: mysql

I've been trying in vain to create a script which will read the date and time column (`2010-12-16 09:52:37`) in this format then delete them.

Can anyone help my column name is called 'generatedAt'.

Answer (score 6):

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [column] < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```